# I get results only for the last class, not all of them

Tags: python, nlp

I am doing a NLP work (just starting to learn) with policy descriptions (corpus) and policy areas (classes). I have calculated the word frequency, and made a list of words with the 100 most frequent terms. I have 27 classes. Some words are relevant for some classes but irrelevant for others, so I cant clean them from all the data set. I want to remove the words in the list from the classes where they are present in LESS than 50% od the rows, but when i print dfen_all it gives me only the results for the last class.
It seems that somehow it is not mergin the datasets for each class... Iàve tried a few modifications but nothing worked.

```
for term in most_common_words_list:
    for class_num in arr2:
        df_class = dfen[dfen['Policycat1'] == class_num] # get dataframe of class
        num_with_term = len(df_class[df_class['corpus3'].str.contains(term, case=False)])# count number of records with term
        num_total= len(df_class['corpus3'])
        percent = num_with_term/num_total
        if percent < 0.5:
            df_class['corpus3_clean'] = df_class['corpus3'].str.replace(term, '') # delete term from records

#join all dataframes into a single dataframe
dfen_all = pd.DataFrame()
for class_num in class_values:
    dfen_all = pd.concat([dfen_all, df_class[df_class['Policycat1'] == class_num]])


#save the dataframe to a csv
#df_all.to_csv('all_classes.csv', index=False)
dfen_all['totalwords_c3cl'] = dfen_all['corpus3_clean'].str.split().str.len()
dfen_all
```

I am expecting to get all the results together in a daframe, not only the last label.

This is my first question, I apologize if I missed something. Thanks a lot!